# How to save data in multiple environments using sqoop command

Tags: sqoop, sqoop2

I need to save the data in both HDFS and AWS S3 at a time. i have used below command but only first given path is working.

```
sqoop import -D mapreduce.job.name=XXX-D mapred.job.queue.name=XX -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=<path> -Dfs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm=####--options-file <path> --query "select cols from DB.Table where UPDATETIME between to_date('2015-09-11 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2018-05-24 04:28:16','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') and \$CONDITIONS" --hive-delims-replacement ' ' --direct --m 1 --split-by ID --target-dir <S3 path> --target-dir <hdfs path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop doesn't support multiple targets. You can try a two step approach:

1. [Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html) import from `DB` to `HDFS`
2. [distcp](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html) from `HDFS` to `Amazon S3`

Comment: tried but facing exception: Unable to load credentials from Amazon EC2 metadata service for distcp